# Redis: :setTimeout() is deprecated PHP 7.2

Tags: php, codeigniter, caching, redis, php-7.2

I started getting this error

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: 8192
>
> Message: Function Redis::setTimeout() is deprecated
>
> Filename: drivers/Session_redis_driver.php

I am using PHP 7.2.27
What best I can do to fix this

Comment: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/changelog.html - they fixed it in 3.1.11 - you should probably update your version to the latest stable release.

Comment: is there any other way to achieve this ?

Comment: Whats the problem ?  did you change the core?

Comment: nothing changed in core file

Comment: like i said - you should update your current version...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please try to replace `setTimeout()` function to `expire()`

Answer (score 1):

Here the solution: [LINK](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/pull/5816)

The code like : `$this->_redis->setTimeout`

Should be : `$this->_expire`

Answer (score 0):

Update your Codeigniter 3 version, currently at `3.1.13`. You can download the current release zip file [here](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/installation/downloads.html). To upgrade:

- Delete (or rename) the current `system` folder
- Extract the zip file and copy the new `system` folder into your app root

I had this issue when setting up my CI app using `docker-compose` and the redis docker image